# Where can I find puzzles of a certain type?

Tags: discussion

I would like to find more puzzles of this type. The quizzer describes some situation with minimal information, and the guesser has to find out the answer to some question (normally "why?")

For example:

1. A woman puts a single shoe into a safe overnight. Why?
2. A man goes to a restaurant, asks for a glass of water, and the waiter points a gun at his head. The man says "Thank you". Why?

Where can I find more puzzles like this?

Comment: This doesn't seem like it rises to the level of being an _answer_, but: (1) One common term for these is "lateral thinking puzzles"; (2) you won't find very many of them _here_, especially recently, because general policy here these days is that puzzles should be things that have _definite correct solutions_ and this sort of lateral-thinking question often has lots, even if one seems like clearly the neatest once you've seen it.

Comment: For instance, consider the second of your examples, which I pick over the first because I know offhand what the intended solution is for the second but not the first. Other not-much-less-plausible solutions: It's for a scene in a film, the restaurant had already agreed to play their part, and the leading actor is thanking the extra for his performance. The man and the waiter are spies and their actions are coded messages. The waiter is a homicidal maniac and the man is hoping to calm him down.

Comment: In this case the actually intended solution is _wittier_ than those, and if any of those were presented as the answer, one good response would be "OK, I guess, but then how is this actually a puzzle?". So there really is a sense in which the intended response is _better_, but it's not clear that it's _righter_ than those are. And current PSE policy is that we only want questions that have single definitely-_right_ answers. (With the caveat that the single right answer might be something like "there are three possibilities, and here they are".)

Comment: As to the actual question of where to find these, I find that a web search for "lateral thinking puzzles" gives quite a lot of results that seem like they might be the right kind of thing, and searching an online bookstore for "lateral thinking puzzles" turns up quite a lot of books that also seem like they might be the right kind of thing. I cannot vouch for the quality of any of those pages or books.

Comment: There is a smartphone app containing many of these puzzles, it is called "Dark stories". I won't put a link here, you can find it by yorself